# How can I put CakePHP templates (CTP files) into HTML?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, ctp-file

Whilst I am familiar with HTML, CSS, SQL and some Javascript, I know nothing about PHP and my hours of searching on the Internet just takes me to tutorials which show me how to build PHP scripts from scratch, which is not helping me. I am not sure I entirely understand the concepts I am dealing with but I will try and explain as best I can.

I have been given a local copy of a database (developed by somebody else who for logistical reasons I cannot contact at the moment) in MySQL, on an Apache Tomcat server and utilising PHP which was developed in CakePHP and so has several templates from CakePHP. These are all running through Wampserver. The database 'BuddyMe' contains 3 tables - User, Roles and Business Units - and there are corresponding Views using the templates from CakePHP for displaying, editing, and adding entries in these 3 tables.

What I have - a series of files in the WWW directory of Wampserver for these views. These views are in CakePHP 'templates' (CTP files).

What I am trying to do - I have a series of HTML files which at the moment are totally separate from the CTP files. How can I incorporate the Views from the CakePHP templates into my HTML files? I've tried including the CTP files within an IFrame, but I get nothing. There are so many files in the Views that I cannot understand which bits of code I need to lift, or how I can otherwise access the Views from within my own HTML files.

I have gone round and round in circles trying to work this out, any help just to get me going in the right direction would be enormously helpful.

Comment: You don't include them in html at all. (Cake)PHP works differently, especially MVC. Please read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html - also see the tutorials.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between Views and Templates? If not, [take a look at the official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html). It is also important that you understand the concept behind MVC architecture

Comment: Hire somebody who knows what to do to get this done for you. The alternative is to spend some time (guess weeks in your case) to learn php, OOP, MVC, CakePHP (in that order).